# How to prompt for password using AJAX and .htaccess?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I am trying to protect an upload script with a password using AJAX + PHP + .htaccess.

My test website is at http://scrabble.stats.org.pl/test/gcg/. If you choose one option from the dropdown list, a table will appear. Then, in the rightmost column, you'll see "Dodaj" ("add") buttons. Their "change" event is handled with AJAX at [line #25](https://github.com/alkamid/gcg-import/blob/af3fa9f70c3f6da16917bd2ac0d0d54e1d8476e8/index.php#L25) (a minimal version below):

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        $('.upload').on('change', function(event) {
            var file_data = $(event.target).prop('files')[0];
            //console.log(file_data);
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({

                url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    var response = $.parseJSON(php_script_response);
                    if ( response.status == 'error') {
                        alert( response.errormsg );
                    }
                    else {
                        $(event.target).closest('.fileUpload').hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

`upload.php` can be found [here](https://github.com/alkamid/gcg-import/blob/af3fa9f70c3f6da16917bd2ac0d0d54e1d8476e8/upload.php). It just saves the contents of the uploaded file to a database. It returns a `$response_array` with `success` or `error` states.

Now, I know how to protect a folder on my server with a .htaccess file and it works fine (check out http://scrabble.stats.org.pl/test/gcg/upl):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/usr/auth.passwd"
require valid-user
AuthName "Protected site"
```

**Is it possible to protect `upload.php` only, so that the website prompts for a password when a user clicks on that "Add" button?**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692067/jquery-ajax-calls-with-http-basic-authentication) and [this](http://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication) and tried those solutions, but they don't seem to work. Usually I am getting this error in Chrome console:

```
http://scrabble.stats.org.pl/test/gcg/upload/upload.php
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not
Allowed)
```

I am afraid I might not understand the above solutions. Firstly, I am not sure about the `btoa(username + ":" + password)` part. Are those special keywords or am I supposed to expose user:pass in those approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Your first link seems to do the right thing.

When clicking on the Add-Button, you need to display a popup or a form by yourself requesting the username and password for your upload.php

You can then submit these data to the server like seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507289/6237870).

The [btoa](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) method encodes your data as base64.

Basically you just send a header for Basic-Auth ("Authorization", ...), and as the data you provide username and password.

> I am afraid I might not understand the above solutions. Firstly, I am not sure about the btoa(username + ":" + password) part. Are those special keywords or am I supposed to expose user:pass in those approaches?

When you login to your server you ALWAYS have to send the username and the password. In `btoa(username + ":" + password)` `username` and `password` are variables you have to set (By reading data from the login form mentioned above).